# Keep div's from stacking vertically using bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

First off the client has a requirement that the core bootstrap files cannot be edited, so all custom css has to be placed in a separate file.

The design I was given has a bunch of boxes that when in the desktop view are laid out in a grid 3 across in one row. This works fine, but the mobile view has those same boxes lined up 2 across, but they keep stacking.  I have tried col-sm-6 inside of a container, and it works between 992px and 762px, but below that, the boxes stack.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You can try col-xs-6 - that's xs for extra-small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the non-stacking `col-xs-*` class..

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/119940